# What to gitignore to protect my OS license (and computer)

Tags: github, gitignore

I'm going to upload a project to github but I'm not sure that if some temporary files or binaries from visual studio, includes some important info about the OS and computer I use, which could(?) let people do hacking.

Which files should I consider ignoring or not uploading from my  project (has C++ and C# parts)?

I already have a github page:

https://github.com/tugrul512bit/Cekirdekler

and using Visual Studio 2015 community edition.

Comment: There are some example `.gitignore` files available for different IDEs here https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: okay, I'm reading that, thank you. there is no C# option there but C++ exists, checking that

Comment: You know you get to look at the files you commit first, right? If you see something you don't want committed, gitignore it.

Comment: @john I haven't uploaded a project before, I thought there could be a way to upload in a single drag drop or something for all project. There are only 35 files in C# part but what about the project settings file? Does any downloader need to re-tune his/hers own poject just as I did once before beggining to write this project?

Comment: Version control software is designed for tracking all files in a project separately from each other. In most situations, nobody should have to edit your csproj / sln file to compile your code. Sometimes you'll have issues with nuget packages, but as long as you provide any non-nuget third party libraries that you use, you should be fine. Just check you have the rights to distribute any third-party non-nuget libraries.

Comment: @john so I use github desktop software to upload? Also do I need turtle svn or similar?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik correct

Comment: @john then I look at templates what colin__s told me about? They don't have C# version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139364/discussion-between-john-and-huseyin-tugrul-buyukisik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore).

Remember that you can always edit it to fit your specific needs, but this should work for VS2015.

Comment: Yes it worked, also wheb I tried to create a new file it asked me if I needed a template(while I was typing .gitignore) then it showed me your link. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome. @huseyintugrulbuyukisik